# WooCommerce category page showing products and subcategories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

My WooCommerce category page showing products and subcategories both and on one category it's only showing products.

In my WooCommerce product display settings "Default Category Display" is set to subcategories.

I have 12 categories but the problem is only with two of them.

Please, how can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the category and set the 'display mode'. The settings are category level override the defaults.